# Leave only alphanumeric symbols in string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-2.x

I am using Python 2.7.  On SO I found the following regexp for removing non-word characters:

```
pat = re.compile('[\W]+', re.UNICODE)
```

I wrote the next function:

```
def leave_only_alphanumeric(string):
  pat = re.compile('[\W]+', re.UNICODE)
  return re.sub(pat,' ',string)
```

Though on the following string:

```
kr\xc3\xa9m
```

it produces the wrong result:

```
kr\xc3 m
```

`\xa9` was deleted from the string, but should not have been.

Comment: How did you create the string? Specifically, if it is in your code, did you prefix the string with a `u`?

Comment: Is your text in a `unicode` object or a `str` object?

Comment: @Bakuriu leave_only_alphanumeric(u'kr\xc3\xa9m')

Comment: That's the issue. It should be `u"kr\xe9m"` or `"kr\xc3\xa9m"`. Otherwise your string has the characters `Ã©` in it, not `é` as you would expect. Thus your code removing the ©, but not the Ã.

Comment: @spectras but what can I do with it? The code of é is indeed \xc3\xa9

Comment: No, the codepoint of `é` is [u00e9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm). What you're confusing it with is it utf-8-encoded form, which is two bytes, `0xc3 0xa9`. Try: `"kr\xc3\xa9m".decode('utf-8')`

Comment: If you are writing unicode text you should: 1) make sure your editor is using utf-8 2) add `# -.- coding: utf-8 -.-` at the top of your file 3) use `leave_only_alphanumeric(u'krém')`. Alternatively use a unicode literal with **unicode escapes**: `u'kr\u00e9m'`. Otherwise, you are writing *bytes* so no `u` prefix and use the two-byte escape you then have to `decode` it into a `unicode` object. You cannot mix the two representations however.

Comment: @ig-melnyk> I put a demonstration of properly decoding the string in my answer. Your function actually works, issue is just in the way you use it.

Comment: By the way, if you really want to be sure to get things right you may consider using the explicit unicode name: `print(u'kr\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE}m') --> krém`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing unicode codepoints and the utf-8 encoding.

The letter you are trying to handle is `é`, code point [u00e9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm).
It is encoded in utf-8 as two bytes, 0xc3 and 0xa9.

Try:

```
>>> "kr\xc3\xa9m".decode('utf-8')
u'kr\xe9m'
>>> print("kr\xc3\xa9m")
krém
>>> print(u"kr\xe9m")
krém
```

With `u""` you must use the actual code points. While with raw `""`, python just sees a chain of bytes.

Note that the second line only works because my terminal's encoding is utf-8, otherwise I'd see garbled output.

As a result, your string is not what you think:

```
>>> print(u"kr\xc3\xa9m")
krÃ©m
```

You actually entered two characters, with codepoint `u00c3` and `u00a9`. The former is `Ã`, which is an alpha character and second is `©`, which is not and is why your code removes it.

Now playing with your code:

```
>>> def leave_only_alphanumeric(string):
...   pat = re.compile('[\W]+', re.UNICODE)
...   return re.sub(pat,' ',string)
...
>>> leave_only_alphanumeric(u"kr\xe9m")
u'kr\xe9m'
>>> leave_only_alphanumeric("kr\xc3\xa9m")   # this is not unicode
'kr\xc3 m'                                   #     -> thus the wrong result
>>> leave_only_alphanumeric("kr\xc3\xa9m".decode('utf-8'))
u'kr\xe9m'
>>> leave_only_alphanumeric("kr\xc3\xa9m".decode('utf-8')).encode('utf-8')
'kr\xc3\xa9m'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe regex might be a bit of an overkill here.

```
def leave_only_alphanumeric(string):
    return ''.join(ch if ch.isalnum() else ' ' for ch in string)
```

**EDIT**: Your title says "alphanumeric" but your code removes digits as well. So there is a bit of unclarity.

Comment: It does not do the same thing.

Comment: @spectras Indeed, but it does now.. :)